# How to split a column value in two part base on their type in SQL/SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

We have a table named DATA containing one column as type varchar(). Following is the value in that column:

```
Raj0014
Dee0052ak
000Pawan
Rah454545ul
```

We need to separate int value and character value, and insert into another table named DATA1 having two columns (id int,name varchar(50)).

Result should be:

```
ID           Name
0014         Raj
0052         Deepak
000          Pawan
454545       Rahul
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind doing this in SQL, you could just select the column twice, and use a load of nested REPLACE functions to replace all of the numbers in one column with nothing, and all of the letters in the other column with nothing. It may look a little messy, but it's probably the fastest option in terms of both development time and performance. Like this, but repeating it for all of the alphabetical characters you need to get rid of:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(data, 'a', ''), 'b', '')
```

And for the second column, again repeating for all of the numeric characters you need to get rid of:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(data, '0', ''), '1', '')
```

If you need/want to do it inside SSIS, you could possibly use the nested replace idea in a Derived Column expression. Other than that, a script component would be the most obvious idea, as long as you're comfortable with working in C# or VB.NET, or work with someone who is - you could then use regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can write on-site script like t-sql to parse your values and pick integers out. Process them using outside script like Perl might be easier.

If you already have a table with all possible ids, you can do a join to remove them from the string values.